# Arquivo exceptions.py

Tags: python, exceção

Programo em python mais ou menos a um ano, e tenho visto sempre em alguns projetos que encontro pela web, um arquivo chamado exceptions.py. Sei tratar exceptions dentro dos meus códigos, esta não é minha duvida.

Gostaria apenas de entender a importancia deste arquivo, e como posso criar e utilizar em meu projeto.

Alguém teria algum documento que pudesse me ajudar a compreender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este é o [documento](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions), mas em Inglês.

Você pode criar exceções personalizadas.

```
class MeuError(Exception): # derivar de Exception
    pass
```

Agora, você pode elevar a excepção

```
raise MeuError
```

ou

```
raise MeuError("foo")
```

A ligação tem mais exemplos

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Um novo classe base por exceptions neste módulo."""
    pass

class InputError(Error):
    """Exceção levantadas por erros na entrada.

    Atributos:
        expr -- expressão de entrada com o erro
        msg  -- explicação do erro
    """

    def __init__(self, expr, msg):
        self.expr = expr
        self.msg = msg

class TransitionError(Error):
    """Gerado quando uma operação tenta uma transição de estado que não é permitido.

    Attributes:
        prev -- o estado no início da transição
        next -- o novo estado tentada
        msg  -- explicação de por que a transição não é permitido
    """

    def __init__(self, prev, next, msg):
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next
        self.msg = msg
```

Substituir o comportamento padrão e fazer suas próprias exceções personalizadas

Comment: Tentei, mas.....